# SQL query if select criteria is null output to be text

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I'm trying to add to an existing SQL query to output "No Data Found" if the entire query is null.

I want to display "No data Found" instead of showing a blank output.

Database I'm writing the SQL query is towards InterSystems Cache. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the query I'm working with

```
SELECT Case
when sn.1_code =  1 then 'Attended  -- ' || 
                          sn.mult_1 || 
                          'and'  ||  
                          sn.dict_2 ||  
                          ' also acted with ' ||  
                          sn.dict_3 || 
                          '.'  
 when sn.1_code =  3 then 'left because ' ||
                          sn.mult_2 ||
                          '.' 
 when sn.dict_1 =  2 then 'Went home' 
 when sn.dict_1 = 24 then 'Canceled' END AS 'Attendance',
sn.dict_2 AS 'Continue'
FROM db.sn
Where sn.dict_2 = 123
```

If the query isnull based on the where clause then output should show a text "NO Data Found for 123 today" instead of what is displaying a blank screen on my system. IF not isnull then will display the data.

```
IF Query isnull output should show
NO DATA FOUND FOR 123 TODAY

If Query not isnull output should show 
Attendance:                                 Continue:
Attended today. Also Acted with respect     Great
Left because not feeling well               Excussed
Went Home                                   Not Excused
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Surround the `CASE` with an `IsNull`:

```
SELECT 
   IsNull(
      CASE
         when sn.1_code =  1 
            then 'Attended  -- ' || 
                 sn.mult_1 || 
                 'and'  ||  
                 sn.dict_2 ||  
                 ' also acted with ' ||  
                 sn.dict_3 || 
                 '.'  
         when sn.1_code =  3 
            then 'left because ' ||
                 sn.mult_2 ||
                 '.' 
         when sn.dict_1 =  2 
            then 'Went home' 
         when sn.dict_1 = 24 
            then 'Canceled' 
      END , 'No Data Found' )  AS 'Attendance'
FROM db.sn
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I I gorgot to add an additional column in the selection criteria. But I need it for the entire selection criteria if isnull to out put "No Data Found"

Comment: Dagz200: your edited query returns two columns per row. Can you provide some samples as to how you'd want the data to output?

Comment: Dagz200: So you're looking to customize your response based on row count, not really a null condition in the data, correct?

Comment: OK we can give that a try if row count = 0 to display "NO Data found for 123 Today" else display data found. Can you show me how that can be done as I have never done it before. Thanks

Comment: I don't have Cache.  Are you using this as a feed for a custom program?

Comment: Yes I'm creating this as a widget based off SQL query pulling the data from Cache

Comment: You should be able to finagle your widget code to detect an empty result set.